# Change default size of User Preferences pop up window

Tags: interface

Is it possible to change the default size of the preferences popup window?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK no, but you can change any area's type to *user preferences* via the menu in the far left of the header:

[image]

You can then temporarily make it the size of the entire blender window by pressing
<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↑ Up arrow</kbd>. Toggle back to the previous screen layout with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↑ Up arrow</kbd> again.
(<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↓ Down arrow</kbd> works too)

If you just want to get to the prefs quickly with more screen real-estate, then perhaps this might help.

Comment: Gandalf, Thanks for the answer. I currently enter the preferences with a button on custom pie menu i am working on. Would it be possible to get to the preferences with any of the layouts that you are showing by pressing a button on my pie menu?, thats what i am after. I will work with Blenders entire UI hidden because my pie gives me everything i need, so entering the preferences by using what you are showing is not an option because in that case i have to bring back parts of the ui only for this function,hope that makes sence.

Comment: @JimmyLivefjord That should be possible; you could make a custom operator in python which changes the current area to user-preferences, then point the pie-menu at that.